# Twitter OAuth library for iOS with Twitter api version 1.1

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm using **Twitter+OAuth for iOS** app but recently it shows `HTTP 410 error` for sharing a post.
I can receive authorization token. Only when I try to share a post it shows the above said HTTP error.

On searching I found out that Twitter has stopped the functioning of API version 1.0.
But **Twitter+OAuth library** is yet using **API 1.0**,hence is there any available updated version of this library with a fix for above issue.

Or is there any way I could fix without waiting for the updated library.

I hope the above makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what is your target iOS version ? iOS 6 has native library for Twitter: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6

Comment: @ShivanRaptor iOS target version is 6 but restriction is of not using native Twitter library.